# Mongoose - create model from existing db data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose, I have a document that was previously pulled from the database, complete with an `_id` property, in raw `Object` format (IE, without all of the document methods, just straight from the db).

How can I use that data to create an instance of `mongoose.Model` without the system assigning the model a new `_id`? I want to then eventually save that model and have it update the existing document in the database.

---

Update: using a combination of @Jack Newcombe's method, and subsequently setting `model.isNew` to `false`, I get the following error: "Mod on _id not allowed". So now it knows to update, but Mongoose is not removing the `_id` field from the update request. There has to be one more system property on the Model that tells Mongoose whether or not to remove the `_id` during an update request. Any ideas?

Comment: When you're fighting upstream like this, it usually means that what you're trying to do is a bad idea and you should rethink why you want to do this. :)

Comment: It's basically to avoid an unnecessary call to `findById` when I already have the data. It's a document ref that is populated onto the main document, and I want to just update the referenced doc from the data that was already sent to the client along with the main document. I *could* do a `findById`, but there's absolutely no need to

Comment: Looks like the answer to my question might also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435461/create-mongoose-model-from-results-of-lean-query/344362274436227

Comment: Another use case for this is when you are using aggregate to query data. You then may want to convert the results into actual models with a specific data projection. To do that, you'd use new Model().

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, but I'm sure there is a better way. I'm surprised there isn't a way to do this easily with Mongoose's API.

Anyway, you need to the following:

1. Create the model like this: `var model = new Model(data,
   {_id:false});`
2. Manually set `model.isNew` to `false`
3. Manually tell Mongoose that the `_id` field hasn't been modified, like this: `delete model.$__.activePaths.states.modify._id`

The reason I'm not so fond of this is because I'm taking advantage of the fact that JavaScript doesn't have true protected methods, and I'm basically hacking Mongoose in order to get it to work. So I'd love to hear other answers if anyone has.

Answer (score -1):

You can prevent the schema for the model from automatically generating an _id by passing in an option that sets the _id to false:

var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { _id: false });

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote but when I try to save the model created with `_id:false` I get a "duplicate key error". IE, Mongoose doesn't know it's supposed to update the existing document.

Comment: Also you used `schema`, instead of `model`.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because, as you can see above, it is incomplete.

Comment: @jraede, you have to use a schema to create the model. The _id option is passed in during schema creation. You can then use mySchema.model to derive a model.

Comment: No you don't. You do `var modelConstructor = mongoose.model('MyModel'); var model = new modelConstructor(data);`

Comment: Look at the code in my answer. That code is taken from the link I provide to the mongoose docs. I am referring *specifically* to passing an _id option to the schema constructor.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant now. But I want the schema to provide an ID in all other cases.