# Create mongoose model from results of lean query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using a lean query to retrieve a large dataset from my database more quickly. Most of the data retrieved is used but not modified or saved, so the lean query is fine, but I need to modify and save a small proportion of the objects using the schema methods.

Is it possible to create the mongoose objects for these results as I iterate through the results of my lean query, leaving the majority of the results in the lean format?

The only way I know of is to create new objects using the data, then set `isNew` to false, but this requires me to make a constructor for this purpose and seems a bit hacky. So I was wondering if there's basically an opposite to `toObject()`

Comment: Did you try creating a new model instance from the lean document?

Comment: Yes, I can create new models, so I can solve the problem, I'm just looking for if there's a better way. I've added details to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Model.hydrate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.hydrate) for this.